# How to prevent divs from overlapping inside the same grid column and row?

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I have two divs, each contains a table. The divs must be placed in the same column, one after another, with no whitespace between them. Right now I have the HTML structured like this, however the 2 tables/divs in column 1 row 1 overlap:

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;">
    <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1;"> {table} </div>
    <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 2;"> {table} </div>
    <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 3;"> {table} </div>
    <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1;"> {table} </div>
</div>
```

The other problem is I'm restricted on the structure for this as well. I'm using Freemarker and the divs are being added into the grid one-by-one in a list. The actual code looks similar to this:

```
<#assign currentCol = 1/>
<#list myMap.values() as container>
    <if container.hasProperty()>
        <#if (currentColumn == 1)>
            <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1;>
        <#elseif (currentColumn == 2)>
            <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 2;">
        <#elseif (currentColumn == 3)>
            <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 3;">
        </#if>
        <div>
            <#include "myTableTemplate.ftl"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <#if (currentColumn == 3)>
            <#assign currentColumn = 1/>
        <#else>
            <#assign currentColumn = currentColumn + 1/>
        </#if>
    </#if>
</#list>
```

My ultimate goal is to have a 3-column display where each of the tables is listed one after another in the columns, without any space between. That is nearly accomplished with this setup. How can I prevent the two divs/tables from overlapping in the same grid cell?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't specify the `grid-row` and `grid-column`, and then if you have `grid-template-columns` with 3 columns defined in it, the items will go into the right cells automatically.

If, for whatever reason, you have to give explicit `grid-row` and `grid-col`, then of course always using `gird-row: 1` won't be good. Then you should do something like this:

```
<#list myMap.values()?chunk(3) as row>
  <#list row as cell>
    ... style="grid-row: ${row?counter}; grid-column: ${cell?counter};" ...
  </#list>
</#list>
```

**Update**:

Other answer based on the image you have added to your question since then. That's a grid that has 3 columns, and only a single row. Inside the grid cell divs, you have further div-s, which will appear under each other inside the cell. So:

```
<div class="myGrid">
  <#list 0..2 as columnIndex>
    <div class="myGridCell">
      <#list myValues?chunk(3) as row>
        <#if row[columnIndex]??>
          <div class="valueBox">
            ${row[columnIndex]}
          </div>
        </#if>
      </#list>
    </div>
  </#list>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't do quite what I want, sorry if I was a little vague in the post. What I'm trying to do is get it so that the layout looks like this https://imgur.com/a/RFLjOtU. Right now #4 gets put into column one at the height level of the bottom of #3, which leaves a ton of whitespace.

Comment: @DSow01 Updated my answer. Please insert the image into your question (not just link it - that can become invalid over time).